# Objective C duplicate symbol issue

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective C.

My app contains 2 view controller. v1 and v2

I need to user a third party SDK in my add. the header is DTDevice.h.

I use this the functions in my v2,so I import DTDevice.h in my v2.h file. However I need to pass a string from v1 to v2. So I import v2.h in v1.h

The app failed built, because one the property in DTDevice.h complain duplicate symbol.

My question is how to pass string from v1 to v2 without reference v2.h inside v1.h.

Thanks very much

Comment: show us your code, in particular the `import` statements in the beginning of the .m and .h files. And the *exact* error message

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing, use predeclaring for header files.

For example if you need `MyClass` object, instead of doing `#import "MyClass.h"` you can predeclare it by doing `@class MyClass`. Predeclarations, as well as imports goes before `@interface` block.
Of course you will have to import `MyClass` in your `.m` by doing standard `#import "MyClass.h"`

As a rule of thumb, try to avoid importing in `.h` files in favour of predeclaring. For classes use `@class` for protocols use `@protocols`. This lets you avoid import cycles.